# asp mvc not show route and title in url after deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a website with ASP.net MVC3.

I have built it up and ran normally at local. Then when I deploy it with IIS 7.5, the site can display. All functionality works except the url is not changing when I switch in between actions and controllers(the url always shows "www.mysite.com" not "www.mysite.com/home/action"). Also, the title of pages are not shown. Instead of my slogan, it shows the domain url like www.mysite.com on the page title of browsers.

I followed the official deploy instruction of ASP.net with IIS.

Is there anyone knows what's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for the Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "ImageWall", // Route name
                "ImageWall/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "ImageWall", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: to be clear, I have set some dlls such as system.web.mvc, system.web.routing to Copy to Local, it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess this might not be an asp.net issue. I am using domain.com as my DNS, the problem may caused by inappropriate setting of it. Anyone familiar with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
The problem is caused by the settings of Domain.com. As I am a fresher to deploy, I didn't set the "A Record" for all my domains. I just set the redirection to my IP.

Answer (score 0):

Regards the title, in your views, do you use something like

`ViewBag.Title = "Some Title"`

In the HTML source of a page on your site, does the `<title>` element get populated? If not, then that could explain why you do not see the title.

Regards the url, can you post the code of your global.asax.cs file please (or global.asax.vb if you're using VB.NET). That is where route configuration can take place, so seeing that could help us explain why the url does not a show.

Comment: Yes, I have set the title and it works locally. All features works locally. I cannot put the code here as it is too long, I'll try to put it in another post.